# displaying images Django

Tags: python, django

Im having trouble getting Django to grab my static files

Relevant Model:

```
    class Poll(models.Model):
        question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', auto_now_add=True)
        image = models.FileField(upload_to='static/')

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.question

        def was_published_recently(self):
            return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
        was_published_recently.boolean = True
        was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published Recently?'
```

settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/Users/austinbailey/ENV/mysite/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'),
]

TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
```

template tag:

```
<img src="{{ poll.image }}" alt="img">
```

what it shows as with inspect element:

```
<img src="media/android_pumpkins_fall_1.jpg" alt="img">
```

this is actually the correct path to the file, but for some reason it only displays the broken image file. I've been working on this for a while now, and I'm stumped. Thanks in advance!

------------------ UPDATE -------------------

I've messed with the structure and the settings in settings.py since the initial post in an attempt to resolve the issue on my own, but here is the structure as of now.

Project Structure:

```
-mysite (root)
  -mysite
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
  -polls (app)
    __init__.py
    urls.py
    models.py
    views.py
    forms.py
    admin.py
    -templates (html for admin site)
    -migrations
  -templates
    -admin
      base_site.html
  -static
    -media
      android_computer_back.jpg
      -2014
        -04
          -13
            android_rose.jpg
          -14
            android_computer_android_studio.jpg
    -static
    -static-only
      -admin ( base stuff for admin site )
        -css
        -js
        -img
  manage.py
  db.sqlite3
```

Relevant Settings from settings.py:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.join(BASE_DIR), 'static', 'static-only')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = 'static/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.join(BASE_DIR), 'static', 'media')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.join(BASE_DIR), 'static', 'static'),
)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
```

Updated Model:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='%Y/%m/%d/')
```

Most Recent Image Tag:

```
<img src="{{ poll.image.url }}" alt="img" />
```

Which shows:

```
<img src="static/media/2014/04/14/android_computer_android_studio.jpg" alt="img" />
```

Database Settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried with `{{ STATIC_URL }}{{ poll.image }}` ?

Comment: Yes, and even that didn't work. Sorry, I should have stated that.

Comment: Weird. Tried `python manage.py collectstatic` ?

Comment: Why is your img src `media/` rather than `static/`?

Comment: I copied and pasted the wrong img src. The src is actually static/android_pumpkins_fall_1.jpg. What I need help with understanding is why if it's pointing to the correct location, why isn't the image being displayed?

Comment: Maybe try using an absolute path to the image and see if it loads it? I'm guessing there's a path problem here.

Comment: Tried that as well. No luck there. I'm new to Django (obviously), but damn this file trouble is frustrating

Comment: Yep. I think file uploads and management is one of the most difficult parts of Django. If you don't mind, could you list your entire project directory structure as well as the code you put in when you do an absolute path to the image? If it's not showing when you do an absolute path, then it's probably not a Django thing. I'm guessing you've got something wrong in the path.

Answer (score 0):

What is going on with your settings? They should look like this:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static-only')
STATIC_URL = '/static'
MEDIA_URL = '/static/media'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static'),
)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)
```

There is no need to call `os` functions twice on everything.

Comment: with that, i get the error 'unable to open database file'

Comment: Then you've got a broken reference to `BASE_DIR` probably somewhere down lower in your settings. You don't show the `DATABASES` portion here.

Comment: updated for database settings. I got the double os functions from a video on youtube

Comment: You see, there you go. `db.sqlite3` is one level **above** your `BASE_DIR`. That's probably the only place you need `os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)`.

Comment: Although I'm not getting errors anymore, the image is still not being displayed. It has the correct file path

Comment: Use your browser debugging tools to figure out what link it is requesting. What happens if you change `<img src...` to `/static...` (leading slash)?

Comment: Tried messing around with it even more, still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Please use the settings below:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'

MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

And call the image field name in templates like so:

```
<img src="{{ model_name.img_field_name.url }}" alt="I will work" />
```

What I've given you above will make you see uploaded files by user whiles working locally. Should you try deploying on in the cloud, somewhere like Heroku, the collectstatic and the bla bla bla things will be done for you automatically.

Lemme know if it doesn't work. Its just an exact snippet found in my current project.

So, an example will be like so:

```
<img src="{{ category.photo.url }}" alt="I will work" />
```

Comment: its the same problem. the file path that is printed by model.img.url is correct, it just doesn't display the image. i may try it on a fresh project and see if it works

Comment: Okay. Go to your admin, and upload a file using the admin interface. Pick this url, and append the name of the file you uploaded. With that, can you do this: http://localhost:8000/media/media/filenaame.jpg ? If you see and image, but can't see it in your templates when you call it, then you're doing something wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured out what the problem was and it of course turned out to be a very clumsy mistake.

I had put my urlpatterns for the media and static files in the wrong spot.

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

They were under the app's urls.py instead of the project's urls.py where the actual folder for the media and static files is located. With this change, the images were being displayed and everything is good now.

Thanks for all the help